# Automatically fill and execute formula to "Cell C2 and so forth" as I enter data in "Cell A2 and so forth"

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Would like to automatically fill Cell (C:C) minus the heading, as I enter data in to Cell (A:A) minus the heading, using VBA. For the formula that I want to automatically fill into Cell C:C is a logic true/false, but instead replaced it with Scanner 1 and 2.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",$A2)),"Scanner 2",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",$A2)),"Scanner 1","Error"))
```

Below is the VBA code I attempted, could it might be wrong since I am new to VBA: (maybe use a function instead of private sub?)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rINT As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim tCell As Range

Set rINT = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
If Not rINT Is Nothing Then
    For Each rCell In rINT
        Set tCell = rCell.Offset(0, 2)
        If IsEmpty(tCell) Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOD_Barcode")
            tCell = tCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""$"",$A2)),""Scanner 2"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""#"",$A2)),""Scanner 1"",""Error""))"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks suspect: `tCell = tCell.Formula = ...`, but it's otherwise not clear what you mean by "it's not working". Can you elaborate? Please revise the question with more detail.

Comment: Also if you're looking to use `Worksheet_Change`, don't rename it to `Autofill_scan_name`.

Comment: Hi yes I was trying to do a worksheet_change , I will revise and elaborate on the question

Comment: Are you sure you want to use this formula in *every single cell* in a column?  Also, I don't believe you can do `tCell = tCell.Formula = ...`  That would just be `tCell.Formula = ...`  Also, is `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOD_Barcode")` the sheet that this `Worksheet_Change()` event is on?  If not, you need to clarify because `tCell` will be whatever the active sheet is...

Comment: @BruceWayne yes I would like to put this formula in every cell within column C (minus the header), yes I believe that is the sheet that is associated with worksheet _change(), but just in case how do i know? New to VBA

Comment: Is using a table - formatted with Ctrl+T - not an option? That would replicate the formula downwards, if I understand your requirements.

Comment: @BigBen I do not think CTRL - T would work .... essentially what I am looking is I want it just like my timestamp code where as i enter the data it adds a timestamp , but now I also want as the time stamp to execute the formula

Comment: Figured out instead of using a VBA instead added formula straight to the cell and enable iteration from the options setting , used: =IF($A2<>"",IF($C2="",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",$A2)),"Scanner 2", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",$A2)),"Scanner 1","Error")),$C2),"")

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a VBA I used a formula straight to the cell and enable iteration from the options setting. Therefore as you enter data it will check if there is data if not- it will run in my case the formula but you can use it for timestamp or any function.

```
=IF($A2<>"",IF($C2="",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",$A2)),"Scanner 2", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("#",$A2)),"Scanner 1","Error")),$C2),"")
```